# Text file to Excel involved multiple table in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I was assigned to created a converter to convert text file to Excel spreadsheet.

I manage to convert them and now I need to put title for each table. Meaning, for every `If..Else` statement in `Do` suppose to have their title.

Instead I just copied them. I tried many things but end up failed. What should I do now?

```
Dim objFSO
Dim TextFile
Dim TextRead
Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
Dim Count

'Open the spreadsheet using the excel application object
ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\Output.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Creating excel object
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath) 'Creating workbook object
Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'worksheets are a member of workbooks, not the Excel Application (Creating sheet object)

'open the text file
Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script

'Name of the text file that need to be convert
TextFile = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"

'Create File system object
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'set the text file to read and open it in read-only mode
set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)

i = 1 'to set row number for Excel paste

SheetObject.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(6).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(8).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(10).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(11).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(12).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(13).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(14).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(15).NumberFormat = "@"

Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
    Line = TextRead.ReadLine

    If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 31, 8)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 7).Value = Mid(Line, 48, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 8).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)
    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1) 'HeaderRecordType to column A
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9) 'ValueHeaderSequenceNo to column b
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19) 'HeaderContractNo to column C
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 10)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 40, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 49, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 7).Value = Mid(Line, 68, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 8).Value = Mid(Line, 69, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 96, 40)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 10).Value = Mid(Line, 136, 40)
        SheetObject.Cells(i,11).Value = Mid(Line, 176, 3)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 12).Value = Mid(Line, 179, 200)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 13).Value = Mid(Line, 379, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 14).Value = Mid(Line, 380, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 15).Value = Mid(Line, 399, 5)
    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "T" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 56, 354)
    Else
        'Error Handling..
    End If

    i = i + 1 'to move down the Excel row to paste for each line in the text file
Loop

'Save and quit
objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

[image: Sample output after converted with no title]

Below sample code show how I tried to add title for each `If..Else` but failed.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim TextFile
Dim TextRead
Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
Dim Count

'Open the spreadsheet using the excel application object
ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\Output.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Creating excel object
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath) 'Creating workbook object
Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'worksheets are a member of workbooks, not the Excel Application (Creating sheet object)

'open the text file
Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script

'Name of the text file that need to be convert
TextFile = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"

'Create File system object
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'set the text file to read and open it in read-only mode
set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)

CountHeader = 2 'to set row number for Excel paste
CountDetail = 4
CountTrailer = 26

SheetObject.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(6).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(8).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(10).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(11).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(12).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(13).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(14).NumberFormat = "@"
SheetObject.Columns(15).NumberFormat = "@"

SheetObject.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Record Type"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Sequence No"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Contract No"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Creation By"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Transaction Date"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Total Record"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Total Amount"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Source"
SheetObject.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Filler"

SheetObject.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Record Type"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Sequence No"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 3).Value = "Contract No"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 4).Value = "Payment Type"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 5).Value = "Settlement Type"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 6).Value = "Effective Date"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 7).Value = "Credit Account No."
SheetObject.Cells(3, 8).Value = "Cr. Transaction Amount"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 9).Value = "Loan Type"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 10).Value = "Bank Employee ID"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 11).Value = "ID Number"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 12).Value = "ID Type Code"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 13).Value = "Bank Employee Name"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 14).Value = "HRIS Process Status"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 15).Value = "Total Record"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 16).Value = "CIF Number"
SheetObject.Cells(3, 17).Value = "Account Branch"

SheetObject.Cells(25, 1).Value = "Record Type"
SheetObject.Cells(25, 2).Value = "Sequence No"
SheetObject.Cells(25, 3).Value = "Contract No"
SheetObject.Cells(25, 4).Value = "Total Record"
SheetObject.Cells(25, 5).Value = "Total Amount"
SheetObject.Cells(25, 6).Value = "Filler"

Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
    Line = TextRead.ReadLine

    If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 31, 8)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 7).Value = Mid(Line, 48, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 8).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)
    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1) 'HeaderRecordType to column A
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9) 'ValueHeaderSequenceNo to column b
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19) 'HeaderContractNo to column C
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 10)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 40, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 41, 8)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 7).Value = Mid(Line, 49, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 8).Value = Mid(Line, 68, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 69, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 10).Value = Mid(Line, 86, 10)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 11).Value = Mid(Line, 96, 40)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 12).Value = Mid(Line, 136, 40)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 13).Value = Mid(Line, 176, 3)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 14).Value = Mid(Line, 179, 200)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 15).Value = Mid(Line, 379, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 16).Value = Mid(Line, 380, 19)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 17).Value = Mid(Line, 399, 5)
    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "T" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 9)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 17)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 56, 354)
    Else
        'Error Handling..
    End If

    CountHeader = CountHeader + 1 'to move down the Excel row to paste for each line in the text file
    CountDetail = CountDetail + 1
    CountTrailer = CountTrailer + 1
Loop

'Save and quit
objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

[Click This for more explaination of the tables.In one sheet divided into 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfKxM.png)

Comment: do you mean that you want a `column header` for each line that gets put into the excel file ... so each line will be two rows -> one row title (header) and one row of actual data?

Comment: can you provide a picture how it should look?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I attached the example how the sheet look like.Thanks

Comment: @Johanness I attached the example how the table in the sheet look like

Comment: Now - if my answer doesn't cut it: what exactly did "fail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You leave space for two rows after the count-header. Yet you increase the countheader variable in every loop.

I think you should move the individual increasers into the respective If clause:

```
  If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then

        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        ....
        SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)
        CountHeader=CountHeader+1
    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1) 'HeaderRecordType to column A
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9) 'ValueHeaderSequenceNo to column b
        ....
        SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 17).Value = Mid(Line, 399, 5)
        CountDetail=CountDetail+1
```

Or you make the 3 parts just two line high, put your header in the first one and insert a line whenever you need it:

```
Sub WriteHeaders(aRange As Range, aHeaders As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(aHeaders, "|")
    aRange.Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
End Sub

Sub ReadMyFile()
  Dim objFSO
  Dim TextFile
  Dim TextRead
  Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
  Dim Count

  ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\Output.xlsx"
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Creating excel object
  Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath) 'Creating workbook object
  Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'worksheets are a member of workbooks, not the Excel Application (Creating sheet object)

  Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script
  TextFile = "C:\Users\MOHDSABRY\Desktop\Converter\taskCon\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"
  set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)
  CountHeader = 2
  CountDetail = 4
  CountTrailer = 6

  WriteHeaders SheetObject.Rows(1), "Record Type|Sequence No|Contract No|Creation By|Transaction Date|Total Record|Total Amount|Source|Filler"
  WriteHeaders SheetObject.Rows(3), "Record Type|Sequence No|Contract NoPayment Type|Settlement Type|Effective Date|Credit Account No.|Cr. Transaction Amount|Loan Type|Bank Employee ID|ID Number|ID Type Code|Bank Employee Name|HRIS Process Status|Total Record|CIF Number|Account Branch"
  WriteHeaders SheetObject.Rows(5), "Record Type|Sequence No|Contract No|Total Record|Total Amount|Filler"

  Select Case Left(Line, 1)
  Case "H"
      SheetObject.Rows(CountHeader).Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
      SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
      '...
      SheetObject.Cells(CountHeader, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)
      CountHeader = CountHeader + 1
      CountDetail = CountDetail + 1
      CountTrailer = CountTrailer + 1
  ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
      SheetObject.Rows(CountDetail).Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1) 'HeaderRecordType to column A
      SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9) 'ValueHeaderSequenceNo to column b
      '...
      SheetObject.Cells(CountDetail, 17).Value = Mid(Line, 399, 5)
      CountDetail = CountDetail + 1
      CountTrailer = CountTrailer + 1
  ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "T" Then
      SheetObject.Rows(CountTrailer).Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
      SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
      '...
      SheetObject.Cells(CountTrailer, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 56, 354)
      CountTrailer = CountTrailer + 1
  Else
      '....
```

Comment: Hi Joanness, It working smoothly.FInally..by any chance do you have any idea to loop if the number of rows we didnt know.Meaning, we cannot set the title for each table unless we know the exact value right?what do you think..Thanks a lot btw

Comment: You could make two lines for every part of the table and then after filling a specific row insert a new one in the respective IF clause.

Comment: I don't get you @Johanness, can you maybe break some of my codes..btw,thanks for your effort again.

Comment: I added another solution that would work with your additional question

Comment: OK. Just now I saw that you also asked this as a second question minutes after you asked me here. While its a good thing to keep separate concerns in separate questions it would have been polite to make this clear here. It would have saved me a bunch of time I could have spent on other questions. (Also: that your data always comes in the same pattern is a vital piece of information that could have made it simpler - as Scott found out in the other thread.